# Django GroupBy that return a different value

Tags: python, django, aggregation

I have a model that looks like this:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

class Department(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    company_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
```

I want to group the departments so that I would know in what company they are under, then return the company name:

```
Database:

    Company                         Department
id         name                 id      company_id  name
C001        aa                  D001      C001      zz
C002        bb                  D002      C002      yy
C003        cc                  D003      C003      xx
                                D004      C001      uu
                                D005      C003      vv
```

What I want is to know the best way to set a query like this, but will return the Company name:

```
Department.objects.filter(id=company_id).groupby(company_id)

Return company_name
```

Expected Result:

```
D001 and D004 is under C001 wherein the name is aa
D002 is under C002 wherein the name is bb
D003 and D005 is under C003 wherein the name is cc
```

Comment: Django doesn't have any group by, are you using a third party package?

Answer (score 3):

It would perhaps be easier to use a ForeignKey instead in your Department model:

```
company = ForeignKey('Company')
```

And then do something like:

`company = Company.objects.get(id=company_id)`
then you'll have:
`company.name` and `company.department_set.all()`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Answer (score 0):

After you relate your models with a ForeignKey, as Pavel wrote, and you have your queryset with all your Departments, you can regroup in the templates:

```
{% regroup departments by company_id as company_list %}
```

Now `company_list` is a list with groups like this, that you only have to style:

```
[
 {grouper: C001, list: [D001, D004]},
 {grouper: C002, list: [D002]},
 {grouper: C003, list: [D003, D005]}
]
```